# How to transition between two custom views based on state change?

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

I have a state variable in an ObservedObject that determines which of two custom views I show in SwiftUI.

I've messed around with .animation(.easeIn) in various locations and tried things with .withAnimation(), but I can't get anything to happen besides XCode complaints while experimenting. Regardless of where I put .animation() I either get a compile error no nothing happens when I run the code. Just flick from one view to another when I trigger a state change.

```
struct EventEditorView : View { /* SwiftUI based View */
    var eventEditorVC : EventEditorVC!

    @ObservedObject var eventEditorDataModel: EventEditorDataModel

    var body: some View {

        switch( eventEditorDataModel.editMode) {
        case .edit:
            EventEditModeView(eventEditorVC: eventEditorVC, eventEditorDataModel: eventEditorDataModel)
        case .view:
            EventViewModeView(eventEditorVC: eventEditorVC, eventEditorDataModel: eventEditorDataModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `.transition` on your elements and `withAnimation` when you change the `value` that affects their state:

```
enum ViewToShow {
    case one
    case two
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewToShow : ViewToShow = .one
    
    var body: some View {
        switch viewToShow {
        case .one:
            DetailView(title: "one", color: .red)
                .transition(.opacity.combined(with: .move(edge: .leading)))
        case .two:
            DetailView(title: "two", color: .yellow)
                .transition(.opacity.combined(with: .move(edge: .top)))
        }
        Button("Toggle") {
            withAnimation {
                viewToShow = viewToShow == .one ? .two : .one
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var title: String
    var color : Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
            .background(color)
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't see an animation with the effect as specified in the example, but with this the animation worked as I'd hoped:                `.transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)))`